# Python Pandas: replace given character if found in column label

Tags: python, replace, pandas, dataframe

I have a df which looks like this:

```
Label                        PG & PCF      EE-LV  Centre    UMP     FN  
Label                                                                    
Très favorable                   2.68       3.95    4.20   3.33   3.05   
Plutôt favorable                12.45      42.10   19.43   2.05   1.77   
Plutôt défavorable              43.95      41.93   34.93  20.15  15.97   
Très défavorable                37.28       9.11   41.44  70.26  75.99   
Je ne sais pas                   3.63       2.91    0.10   4.21   3.22
```

I would simply like to replace "&" with "and" where found, either at the column labels or index labels.

I would've imaged that something like this wouldve worked but it didn't...

```
dataframe.columns.replace("&","and")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried won't work as `Index` has no such attribute, however what we can do is convert the column into a Series and then use `str` and `replace` to do what you want, you should be able to do the analagous operation on the index too:

```
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns).str.replace('&', 'and')
df
Out[307]:
                    PG and PCF  EE-LV  Centre    UMP
Label                                               
Très favorable            2.68   3.95    4.20   3.33
Plutôt favorable         12.45  42.10   19.43   2.05
Plutôt défavorable       43.95  41.93   34.93  20.15
Très défavorable         37.28   9.11   41.44  70.26
Je ne sais pas            3.63   2.91    0.00   4.21
```